# How to compare the growth rate of these two functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, asymptotics

Given two functions: $\log_{10}(n^{\sqrt n})$ and $\log_2(n^2!)$, how to determine which grows faster when $n\to\infty$.

I tried to use some logarithm rules to simplify them and compare but this seems not helping:
$\log_{10}(n^{\sqrt n})$ = $\sqrt n \log_{10}n$, and I have no idea how to deal with the factorial.

I know I can use online grapher, but anyway is there a way to determine it without graphing?

Comment: [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).

Comment: Use the Stirling's approximation.

Comment: Is it $(n^2)!$ or $(n!)^2$, if it's the first how many numbers in the expansion of $1\cdot 2\cdots n^2$ are bigger than $n$?

Comment: The post says $n^2!$ and not $n!^2$, therefore it should be $(n^2)!$.

Comment: @kingW3 It's $(n^2)!$